# MySQL ignoring the options I set in ~/.my.conf

Tags: mysql

I am trying to turn off ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in my local ~.my.cnf options file.

Here are my system details:

```
$ sudo service mysql status
 * /usr/bin/mysqladmin  Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.7.25, for Linux on x86_64
Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Server version          5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2
Protocol version        10
Connection              Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket             /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:                 19 min 35 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 14  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 108  Flush tables: 1  
Open tables: 27  Queries per second avg: 0.011`
```

~.my.cnf has the following content:

```
[mysqld]
key_buffer_size=32M
max_allowed_packet=512M 
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE, 
ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

---

When I use "mysqld --help --verbose" this is what I see:

```
$ sudo mysqld --help --verbose
mysqld  Ver 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Starts the MySQL database server.

Usage: mysqld [OPTIONS]

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

So my ~/.my.cnf is being read last meaning that it should override any settings made in previous files.

---

When I use "mysqld --print-defaults" to see what is being set, here's what I get:

```
$ sudo mysqld --print-defaults
mysqld would have been started with the following arguments:
--user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid 
-- socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306 --basedir=/usr 
--datadir=/var/lib/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp --lc-messages-dir=/usr/share/mysql 
--skip-external-locking 
--bind-address=127.0.0.1 --key_buffer_size=16M --max_allowed_packet=16M 
--thread_stack=192K --thread_cache_size=8 
--myisam-recover-options=BACKUP --query_cache_limit=1M 
--query_cache_size=16M --log_error=/var/log/mysql/error.log 
--expire_logs_days=10 --max_binlog_size=100M --key_buffer_size=32M 
--max_allowed_packet=512M 
--sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,
    ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

It would appear my settings have been actioned.

---

Using another method shows the same:

```
$ sudo mysqladmin variables | grep sql_mode
| sql_mode   
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,
ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

$ sudo mysqladmin variables | grep max_allowed_packet
| max_allowed_packet| 16777216
```

---

However, when I look at the settings of sql_mode and max_allowed_packet in mysql itself I see they still have their system default values:

```
$ mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 5
Server version: 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 (Ubuntu)    
Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> select @@global.sql_mode;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@global.sql_mode                                                        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,                  |
| NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,             |
| NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+

mysql> select @@global.max_allowed_packet;
+-----------------------------+
| @@global.max_allowed_packet |
+-----------------------------+
|                    16777216 |
+-----------------------------+
```

What am I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your personal `~/.my.cnf` can only affect programs run by you, for example `mysql` client or `mysqldump`, etc.

It does no good to write a section for `[mysqld]` in your personal `~/.my.cnf` file, because your user is probably not the one who launches mysqld.

You could declare your preferred sql_mode for your own sessions in the MySQL client by writing the option into a `[client]` section:

```
[client]
max_allowed_packet=512M 
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE, 
ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

But `[client]` only applies to MySQL tools like `mysql` and `mysqldump`. It doesn't affect any of your own apps, like if you code something in Java, Python, Ruby, or PHP, etc.

If you want an option to affect all clients, including your apps, you must apply the option in the global MySQL Server config, which is probably `/etc/my.cnf` as described in the other answer.

You can also change many global options dynamically without restarting mysqld. I often do this right after I edit the `/etc/my.cnf` file, so I can get the change without interrupting service.

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL sql_mode='...whatever...';
```

Final note: I recommend NOT disabling ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. That sql_mode is a useful way to prevent bogus query results. It's much better to keep that sql_mode enabled, and fix your SQL queries so they don't cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

mysqld usually runs as its own user `mysql`, so `~/.my.cnf` is meaningless unless it is in the home directory of the `mysql` user.  For server configurations, you typically put settings in the `/etc/my.cnf` file or `/etc/my.cnf.d` depending on your mysql version.